# ls: : Operation not permitted - Mojave security?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, high-sierra, mojave

Is this directory protected by Mojave's new security features?

```
$ sudo ls -laR /var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/
ls: Operation not permitted
```

It works in High Sierra but not Mojave. How do we view the contents of this directory?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can turn it of System Integrity Protection (the SIP) but be aware of potential risks.

**to disable**

Reboot the Mac and hold down Command + R.

From the Utilities menu, choose Terminal.

Type `csrutil disable`

To turn it back on --**Highly Recommended** !!

You can re-enable SIP by following the above steps, but using `csrutil enable` instead.

Comment: awesome. thanks so much. where did you learn to do that? is there some official SIP/Mojave documentation i can use to better understand technical details?

Comment: it was there before Mojave, Apple just made it more stringent in Mojave.

Comment: Disabling SIP is massive overkill, and completely unnecessary to solve the problem. It opens your system to all sorts of vulnerabilities. It's like removing your front door because someone needs to enter your house. 
See the answer about Full Disk Access in System Prefs for a better way.

Comment: @benwiggy Giving Terminal full-access is just as bad. I think I'd ask why the OP thinks he needs to be manipulating that directory.

Comment: I'd argue "less bad".

Comment: @MarcWilson for example because one wants to link an executable from `/usr/bin` to a newer version installed by homebrew that lives in `/usr/local/bin`. This seems to be permitted (at least in Mojave).

Comment: @Robin Perhaps you've heard of this thing called $PATH?

Comment: @MarcWilson Yes, I know about the concepts of `$PATH`. In my case `/usr/local/bin` is within the PATH and even listed before `/usr/bin` so it "should" take precedence over `/usr/bin` - but my rsync version from `/usr/bin` was used anyways :shrug:

Comment: You can use ```csrutil enable --without fs``` for a slightly safer alternative.

Comment: Yeah, poor decision. First step for every new Mac: disable system integrity protection.

Answer (score 90):

A less drastic way:

Go to System Preferences > Security & Privacy and give Full Disk Access to Terminal.

*Adapted from https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8637915*

Comment: Did not work for me in Mojave (v10.14.1) - I am still getting `Operation not permitted`

Comment: Worked for me on Mojave 10.14.4 using iTerm2 as my terminal.

Comment: Are your terminals closed when you added it in Privacy->Full Disk Access?

Comment: Doesn't matter whether the terminal is closed or not. In any case, I can conform what Robin said for 10.14.5, it does *not* work (Terminal app is added to Full Disk Access list), even after a reboot.

Comment: I can confirm that this worked on macOS Mojave 10.14.6; closing Terminal _was_ required (and prompted for with `"Terminal.app" will not have full disk access until it is quit`); rebooting the computer was not necessary. Thanks!

Comment: Trust me, it does *not* work for me (nor for Robin), I closed the terminal many times...

Comment: Solved error `Operation not permitted` on `ls ~/Documents` after upgrading to MacOS Catalina 10.15.5

Comment: Worked for me in macOS Mojave 10.14.6 after quitting and re-starting Terminal. Reboot was not necessary. I suspect Apple fixed this between 10.14.5 and 10.14.6

Answer (score 25):

[This did it for me](http://osxdaily.com/2018/10/09/fix-operation-not-permitted-terminal-error-macos/)

Steps:

** Apple menu** -> 
**System Preferences** -> 
**Security & Privacy** -> 
**Privacy** -> 
**Full Disk Access ->** +

Choose:

**Applications** -> **Utilities** -> **folder** -> **Terminal** -> **open/grant terminal full disk access privileges.** -> **Relaunch terminal**

Comment: How does this differ from earlier answer https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/345142/237?

Comment: @Mark It provides full steps, not partial steps which weren't enough for me to figure it out looking at the answer you mentioned, along with a guide that has pictures.

Comment: Works for me on latest Monterey.

Answer (score 2):

In my case helped simply:
`chflags -R nouchg .`
This code I used in terminal in folder with problematic file.
Source: https://txcowboycoder.wordpress.com/2011/01/10/svn-cant-move-svntmpentries-operation-not-permitted/

Answer (score 0):

that way worked for me

Go to *System Preferences > Security & Privacy* and give Full Disk Access to **Terminal** and **sshd-keygen-wrapper**