# cp from shell (Terminal) or Finder: "Operation not supported"

Tags: terminal, finder, bash, permission, smb

An odd issue here after an upgrade from High Sierra to Catalina.  When I try to copy files from an SMB network share in the Terminal (bash and zsh), I get:

```
$ cp /Volumes/share_name/path/file.ext  ~/Documents 
cp: /Volumes/share_name/path/file.ext: Operation not supported
```

When I try to copy the same file via Finder, I get "The operation can't be completed because it isn't supported":

[image: screenshot]

I've tried to execute this with `sudo` and I've tried to repair user permissions (user ID is501, so: `sudo diskutil resetUserPermissions / 501`) and the same results.

***Important to note: Other systems with Catalina work just fine with the same SMB share.***

Comment: That type of error is usually a file permission (user) error on the SMB share.  What SMB version is that server running?  Is there a valid user account on the server?  Are the permissions set correctly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ls: : Operation not permitted - Mojave security?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/339862/ls-operation-not-permitted-mojave-security)

Comment: @Allan as noted in the body, this does work fine on other systems - that means that this same user account with the same auth info works 100% fine on other macOS Catalina (and Mojave) installs. It's a Windows 2019 Server.

Comment: @anki unfortunately no: SIP was (is) already off. Additionally with Terminal.app added to `Full Disk Access` it behaves the same way, ie: with failure.

Comment: @Allan let me qualify this further after doing some more testing: it appears as though while other systems are able to copy just fine on the same share, I AM able to mount macOS SMB shares and copy to and from those fine. It does appear that this is some strange interaction between Windows 2019 Server and Catalina - but it doesn't really make sense since other macOS Catalina systems DO interact without issue.  Maybe some kind of an SMB client setting that's wonky for this specific machine?

Comment: @Allan so yes, that was it. I placed it into an answer here.

Answer (score 4):

It turned out that the problem was actually an existing `/etc/nsmb.conf`. When this was removed the SMB client behavior returned to normal in this regard. Within it, the previous user had defined:

```
[default]
signing_required=no
protocol_vers_map=1
```

Comment: Glad you got it all sorted out!